# Is there a way to make the visible excel chart the active chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, visible

I am writing some vba code and wanted to know if there is a way to change the Active chart in a worksheet by selecting the chart that is not hidden/is made visible?

I have elsewhere hidden 5 of my 6 charts depending on other variables. This functionality is all working okay.

However, I now want to only want to change the series colour of the chart that is visible.

```
If Sheets("sales").Range("comparator ").Value = "ada" Then
 Sheets("sales").Range("d93:d95,J93:j94,O43:P43").Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_1").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_2").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_3").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_4").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_5").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_6").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166)

ElseIf Sheets("sales").Range("comparator ").Value = "sec" Then
Sheets("sales").Range("d93:d95,J93:j94,O43:P43").Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_1").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_2").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_3").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_4").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_5").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("comparator_6").Activate
 ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 45, 129)

End If
```

When I run the code at the moment I get the error code:
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)':
Requested Shapes are locked for selection

This is because 5 of my 6 charts are hidden. I only want to change the colour of the one that is visible.
The chart that is visible will change depending on other variables, hence why I do not want to specify the chart.

Is there a way to only activate the chart on the active sheet if it is visible?

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: [`ChartObject.Visible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chartobject.visible) might be useful. Note: I doubt you actually need to `Activate` here. `...ChartObjects("chartname").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2)....`

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! I am now getting the error code 9: subscript out of range for the following code  
``` Sheets("sales").Activate
    Charts("comparator_1").FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166) 
```   
If I comment out the first line I get the following error 
'The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type'

Comment: Should be `Sheets("sales").ChartObjects("comparator_1").Chart...`

Comment: amazing thank you!!